# xlsxwriter: resolve the 'xl_col_to_name(col)' to value used in worksheet.set_column()

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

The first example works as expected.  It hides column "A".  What I want to do is hide a column dynamically based on some value.  The xl_col_to_name() function will change a number to a letter.  I want to alter the the function from (A:A) to (col:col) as I attempted several ways in example2 below.

How can I get the worksheet.set_column() to resolve the xl_col_to_name(col) function?  Here is one error I got from an attempt:
File "\xlsxwriter_xl_col_to_name_example.py", line 22
worksheet.set_column("'"xl_col_to_name(col, False)':'xl_col_to_name(col, False)"'", None, None, {'hidden': True})
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks
Dan

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_col_to_name

# EXAMPLE 1 Works as expected.  Hides column "A"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('xl_col_to_name_example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("xl_col_to_name_example")

mylist=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
for col in mylist:
  print(xl_col_to_name(col, False))
  worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, None, {'hidden': True})
  worksheet.write(0,   col+1, 'NUM')
  worksheet.write(1, col,  'some value')
  
workbook.close()

# EXAMPLE 2 - I want to resolve the 'xl_col_to_name(col)' to a value that represents a column to hide.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('xl_col_to_name_example2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("xl_col_to_name_example2")

mylist=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
for col in mylist:
  print(xl_col_to_name(col, False))
  worksheet.set_column("'"xl_col_to_name(col, False)':'xl_col_to_name(col, False)"'", None, None, {'hidden': True})
  worksheet.write(0,   col+1, 'NUM')
  worksheet.write(1, col,  'some value')
  
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to format strings in Python such as the original printf style `%` operator, the string `.format()` method or the new `f''` strings:

```py
>>> import xlsxwriter
>>> from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_col_to_name
>>> col = 0

>>> '%s:%s' % (xl_col_to_name(col, False), xl_col_to_name(col, False))
'A:A'

>>> '{}:{}'.format(xl_col_to_name(col, False), xl_col_to_name(col, False))
'A:A'

>>> f'{xl_col_to_name(col, False)}:{xl_col_to_name(col, False)}'
'A:A'
```

However, the best way to do this is to avoid the string formatting and just use the numbers directly. Almost all of the xlsxwriter methods support `A1` style ranges but they all support numeric arguments as well so it is better to use the number directly:

```py
worksheet.set_column(col, col, None, None, {'hidden': True})
```